# C# - DataSource of comboBox1 depended on comboBox2 value

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox

I have created two classes as per below:

```
class City
{
public string CityName { get; set; }
public string Region { get; set; }

public City(string sCountryName, string sLanguage)
{
    this.CityName = sCountryName;
    this.Region = sLanguage;
}
public override string ToString()
{
    return CityName;
}

class Country
{
public string CountryName { get; set; }
public City[] cities;

public Country(string sCountryName, City[] sCities)
{
    this.CountryName = sCountryName;
    this.cities = sCities;
}
```

After that I have created objects of usa_cities and german_cities as per below:

```
City[] usa_cities = new City[] {new City("Washington", "English"),
                        new City("New York", "English"),
                        new City("San Francisco", "English") };

City[] german_cities = new City[] {new City("Berlin", "German"),
                        new City("Hamburg", "German"),
                        new City("Frankfurt", "German") };
```

And then I have created an object 'countries' as per below:

```
Country[] countries = new Country[] {new Country("USA", usa_cities),
                                    new Country("Germany", german_cities) };
```

In my application I have two comboboxes.
The first combobox allows user to choose a country as per below:

```
        comboBox1.DataSource = countries;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CountryName";
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = -1;
```

I would like to set comboBox2.DataSource depending on the value choosen in comboBox1.
For example - user chooses 'USA' in first combobox - and the second combobox should be filled with usa_cities.
If user chooses 'Germany' - then second combobox should be filled with 'german_cities'.

Could you please advise how can I do it?

Thank you,

Comment: I would set combox2 on the SelectedIndexChanged event that fires when combox1 value is selected. Here's the link to the event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Event handler for the `ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` event which you then use to Change the `ItemsSource` of ComboBox2 based on a case of `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex`